# Can I get Assets from a specific Matrix block?

Tags: templating, matrix

When they exist, I'd like to get specification PDFs from a product entry. They're stored in a `productInfo` Matrix field, in a `specifications` block that has a `downloads` Assets collection.

Naturally I attempted the following...

```
{% set specFiles = entry.productInfo.specifications.downloads %}
{% for specFile in specFiles %}
    {{ specFile.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

...and Craft thought I was being greedy:

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> Craft\ElementCriteriaModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "specifications".

I noticed in [this SE question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/39/search-matrix-for-blocks-with-upcoming-dates) that examples skipped referencing the block type and went straight for the field name, so I tried that next...

```
{% set specificationDownloads = entry.productInfo.downloads %}
{% for specFile in specificationDownloads %}
    {{ specFile.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

This didn't throw any error, but it didn't return any results either.

I know that I can loop through the blocks and then the downloads, it just seems excessive...

```
{% for block in entry.productInfo %}
    {% if block.type == 'specifications' %}
        {% for specFile in block.downloads %}
            {{ specFile.title }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

So what *is* the most straightforward way to get results when I want to limit them to a specific (Assets) field within a certain Matrix block type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do this like so:

```
{% for block in entry.productIndo.type('specifications') %}
    {% for download in block.downloads %}
        {{ download.url }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Of if the nested loops don't suit you:

```
{% set specificationBlock = entry.productIndo.type('specifications').first() %}

{% if specificationBlock %}
    {% for download in block.specificationBlock %}
        {{ download.url }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```